# How to solve this error while installing kubuntu repository in ubuntu 16.04? screenshot link below

Tags: kubuntu

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l71S3.png)

I executed the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```

but the terminal shows

```
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```